# Problem with request body params - how to handle error code 500?

Tags: ktor

This is my params model:

```
data class ProductParams(
    val name: String,
    val key: String,
    val parentProduct: Int?,
)
```

I send params:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "parentProduct": null,
    "key": "TEST"
}
```

I get error code 500. How can I handle it?

Comment: I forgot to add that this is server-side implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

Try setting name param to a String not null as its not an optional val.

Take a look at [Http Status Codes](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) in your case 500 refers to an Internal Server Error. A simple way to handle http status codes is to just check if the request was successful and not handle every single status code. :)

```
if(status == 200){
    // Request Success
}else{
    // Request Failed
}
```